# Automatically recording electronic fund transfers for members

Tags: civimember, custom-fields, batches

We will receive a lot of individual transactions via automated electronic funds transfers from our members' internet banks. I would like to record these, but it seems very cumbersome to do "Batch Data Entry" for each individual member and each individual transaction.

Is there any way in Civi to automatically record these EFTs every month (linked to the member in question)?

Kindest regards, 
Frederik Federspiel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There would not be an automatic process.

Save a CSV spreadsheet(s) with the list of transactions. Every month, you can change the date column and import it into Civi.